# Is my understanding of Relative Topology correct for manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am slowly encountering manifolds in my lectures, and am interested in the notion of open in relative topology with respect to manifolds:

> Let $M\subseteq \mathbb R^{d}$ be an $n-$dimensional manifolds: it
>   follows $\forall  a \in M,\exists V\subseteq \mathbb R^{d}$ open in
>   relative topology on $M$ and $\exists T \subseteq \mathbb R^{n}$ and a
>   chart $\varphi: T \to V$

My main interest is the reason why we go to the lengths of including sets open in relative topology on $M$ rather than just open sets? What is the reason behind this?

I understand relative the topology of $M$, where $\gamma$ is the topology on $\mathbb R^{d}$, is described by $\tau_{M}:=\{M\cap B: B \in \gamma\}$

Comment: Do you mean we consider relative neighbourhoods to $M$ instead of neighbourhoods of $\mathbb R^d$?

Comment: It's saying exactly for all $a\in A$ there is a $V\subseteq M$ open in $M$. Relative openness is important, because usually (whenever $n<d$) $\ M$ cannot contain a $d$ dimensional ball, so its subsets can't be open in $\Bbb R^d$, only in $M$.

Comment: @Berci but my definition of $\tau_{M}$ is correct, right? Or, is it $\gamma$ is topology on $\mathbb R^{n} $ rather than $\mathbb R^{d}$

Comment: Yes, correct. It's from the outer space $\Bbb R^d$.